# Lanzar múltiples chromedriver para prueba de carga

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, chromedriver, ram

Necesito simular el comportamiento real de una aplicación, lo cual la única manera que tengo de hacerlo es lanzando un programa de selenium con chromedriver. Esto es así, porque necesito navegar por la página simulando un usuario.

Mi duda surge como puedo simular unos 1000 usuarios? Porque lanzar tantos navegadores creo que es inviable por el consumo de memoria RAM.

Espero que alguien me ayude. Gracias

Comment: ¿Has resuelto tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Con qué tipo de problema se encontró con la necesidad de emular el trabajo de los usuarios a través de la solución Selenium WebDriver?

Si está seguro de que esto no se puede omitir, hay varias opciones para ejecutar desde JMeter el código que realiza la prueba en Selenium Webdriver.

1. Puedes usar [WebDrvier Components for Apache JMeter](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver).
   Para esto:
   1.1 Descargar [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/)y póngalo en el directorio `lib/ext`, luego reinicie JMeter. 
   1.2 Abierta `Options` - `Plugins Manager` - `Available Plugins` y encontrar e instalar `Selenium/WebDriver Support`.
   1.3. Agregar al elemento de configuración del plan de prueba - `Chrome (or Firefox\PhantomJS..) Driver Config`, y especifique la ruta a WebDriver aquí.
   1.4. Poner `WDS Sampler` a `Thread Group`.
   1.5. Aquí hay un código de muestra dentro de WDS Sampler:

   ```
   //1a. Start capturing the sampler timing  
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()  
   // 2. Perform the Sampler task  
   WDS.browser.get('http://google.com.au')  
   // 1b. Stop the sampler timing  
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()  
   // 3. Verify the results  
   if(WDS.browser.getTitle() != 'Google') {  
       WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false)  
       WDS.sampleResult.setResponseMessage('Expected title to be Google')  
   }
   ```

Pero tenga en cuenta que para emular una carga sustancial, necesitará una gran cantidad de PC, como dice la documentación oficial:

> From experience, the number of browser (threads) that the reader creates should be limited by the following formula:
>
> ```
> C = N + 1
> ```
>
> where C = Number of Cores of the host running the test
>   and N = Number of Browser (threads).
>   eg, if the current reader's host has 4 cores, the formula would yield:
>   4 = 3 + 1
>   meaning that the script should have a MAXIMUM of 3 threads.

Si necesita ejecutar 1000 usuarios simultáneos, verifique el segundo ejemplo.

2. Puede usar Selenium WebDriver para crear y ejecutar pruebas de rendimiento en la cloud servces. Por ejemplo puedes usar [RedLine13](https://www.redline13.com), mira esto [video instruction](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/02/using-selenium-webdriver-run-scalable-load-tests/) o vea las instrucciones paso a paso [how to run Load test with Selenium in the cloud](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/02/selenium-webdriver-cloud-performance-testing/).